# Cannot reopen session after launching startx on UBUNTU

Tags: session, ubuntu, xorg

I had an issue with Xorg so I launched startx from my terminal on ubuntu.
It wasn't working well (only my wallpaper was on the screen after I launch the command). Then I force to shut down.

My actual problem is I cannot reopen my session. When I turn on my computer the opening screen of ubuntu appears and when I enter my password it buckle up on this screen and ask me to enter my password again. It is not a problem of password as in the case I give a wrong password it is asked to me to retape my password.

Can someone have an idea of what the problem is ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It might be better suited to ask in [https://askubuntu.com/](https://askubuntu.com) than here. Also the info you provide is not quite enough to help. Please provide info on your release, Ubuntu, Xorg, etc. etc.

Comment: The only information about the release I have it about ubuntu (12.4). I have no more information to provide as I cannot check any thing on my session (I cannot launch anything, even a terminal)

Comment: You should be able to access your non-X terminal by e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F1

Comment: That is working. I succeed at launching the non-x terminal, but what should I do to launch a graphic session ? I am a beginner on linux :-(

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Ubuntu 12.4 uses `lightdm`, so it would be something normally like `sudo service lightdm restart`, see what happens

Comment: It is driving me on the login screen but it is still buckling up on this screen when I enter my password. After reconsideration its ubuntu 14.04.1. I have the other release on another boot but I don't use it.

Comment: See if you can retrace your steps up until it failed. Did you update something? Did you play with settings? Also check your logs, e.g. `dmesg` or your Xorg log

Comment: I haven't done anything except launching startx from my terminal and force the computer to shut down because I get nothing except my wallpaper on the screen. Can I find something in the log located : .cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash__usr_bin_Xorg.0.crash.log.gz?

Comment: log files are located in `/var/log/`. There you should find your `Xorg.log`. Also type `dmesg` in the terminal and see if there are any errors.